# Disable Firefox 50 search suggestions in location bar

Tags: firefox, search, duckduckgo

I'm on a completely fresh install of Firefox 50.1.0 on Ubuntu, and I keep getting unwanted search suggestions in the location bar:

[image]

I have *not* visited the URLs in this list, i.e., these are *not* items from my history.

This is despite having turned off search suggestions as described here: [Firefox's search suggestion settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1045714/firefoxs-search-suggestion-settings)

In particular, in `about:preferences#search`, I have unchecked both "Provide search suggestions" and "Show search suggestions in location bar results". I have also verified in `about:config` that `browser.urlbar.suggest.searches` is `false`.

This is only in the *location bar*. In the *search bar*, my settings are honored, i.e., there I do not get suggestions. Has something changed in recent Firefox versions, do I need to configure something else to get rid of these searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was my fault, but the fix may be useful for others for future reference:

I wanted to set DuckDuckGo as my search engine, so I visited https://duckduckgo.com/ and followed their "Add DuckDuckGo to Firefox" link. I though this would only set it as my default search engine, but in fact it *installed an extension "DuckDuckGo Plus"* which seems to have produced these results that did not honor my privacy settings. Going to the Add-ons menu and removing this extension fixed the problem.

Comment: When you have a minute to spare, now that the 2-day waiting period has passed you can mark your own suggestion as the official answer.